# How do I define relation between users and points in Eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables:

- Users - for storing users
- User_point - for associacion between users and points(has only user_id and point_id)
- Points for description of points(id, amount, description)

How do I define a relation between these? I tried

```
 public function points(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Point', 'user_point');
}
```

but when I do

```
return $user->points()->sum('amount');
```

it returns just one

Edit:
At first I tried making it like this as it makes more sense:

```
 public function points(){
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Point');
    }
```

But it wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

`SUM` is an aggregate function and so it *should* only return one row.

`$user->points` will be a collection of points attached to that user.

`$user->points()` is a query that you can do additional work against (i.e. `$user->points()->whereSomething(true)->get()`).

Comment: Hey,
My $user variable is one selected user so if I want to get sum of his points I would do $user->points()->sum('amount'); And by 1 I mean wrong sum not one row. My problem is - it just finds user_id=7 and point_id=1 but I want user_id=7 and all point_ids

Answer (score 0):

As user ceejayoz pointed out, using `user->points()` is going to return a builder which you can do additional work on.  I believe using `sum()` on that will look at the first row returned which is what you indicated is actually happening.

Likely, what you really want to do is `$user->points->sum('amount');`

That will get the sum of that column for the entire collection.